# Django not showing new changes in production

Tags: django, uwsgi

I've changed env file and models.py for media app.  When i check the files, the code shows the latest version, which is correct.  When i visit the page, i don't see any changes.  On my local environment i see the changes.

I've done the following

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
```

then i tried touch on uwsgi/admin.ini

```
touch admin.ini
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
```

then i deleted `__pycache__`

I restarted the instance and the changes aren't showing?

I checked the env file and still using old credentials.

There are no errors in the logs?  How can i debug this?